# Should we burninate [jsr303]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [jsr303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsr303) tag seems largely unused and its meaning is covered by [bean-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bean-validation)

Perhaps it would be better off burninated.

Comment: There are a total of 3 questions with this tag.  You can easily remove the tag and it will disappear the next time the tag clean-up runs (nightly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested by bluefeet, I manually removed the tag wherever it was being used. It should be gone tomorrow.